# How to bind Model Fields inside another Model in the Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Model (Register.cs) that contains 2 other Model (ProfileMeta ,ProfileDetail) as fields. How do I bind these 2 Model fields in my Controller class? When I name my 2 field objects the same as the Model file names, as I've seen. When I reference them in ProfileController, they're seen as types and not objects.

```
Error   26  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ContosoUniversity.Models.ProfileMeta.password.get'   C:\Projects\DatingSite\datingSite\ContosoUniversity\Controllers\ProfileController.cs    63  40  DatingSiteInitial
```

However, when I rename them to different names, and refer them like so in ProfileController, I get the compilation error below:
  " doesn't exist in the current context"

Models/Register.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Models
{
    public class Register
    {
        public ProfileMeta ProfileMeta { get; set; }
        public ProfileDetail ProfileDetail { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controllers/ProfileController.cs:

```
// POST: Profiles/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ProfileMeta,ProfileDetail")] Register register)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Add 1 ProfileMeta row and 1 linked ProfileDetail row
                ProfileMeta profileMeta = new ProfileMeta();
                //How to refer to bound: ProfileMeta, ProfileDetail fields inside Register.cs?
                profileMeta.Username = ProfileMeta.Username;
                profileMeta.password = ProfileMeta.password;
                profileMeta.ID = ProfileDetail.ID;
                db.ProfileDetails.Add(ProfileDetail);

                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(profileDetail);
        }
```

Views/Profile/Create.cshtml:

```
@model ContosoUniversity.Models.Register
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Profile</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProfileMeta.Username, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProfileMeta.Username, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProfileMeta.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProfileMeta.password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProfileMeta.password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProfileMeta.password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProfileDetail.Age, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProfileDetail.Age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProfileDetail.Age, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: `profileMeta.Username = register.ProfileMeta.Username;`, but since your model contains an instance of  `ProfileMeta` why create another one? you could just use `db.ProfileDetails.Add(register.ProfileMeta);`

Comment: And what is `return View(profileDetail);`? It wont compile since you don't have a variable named `profileDetail`. Do you mean `return View(register);`?

Comment: unclear!! you want to save ProfileMeta or ProfileDetail or both?? On which line you get error? You have not used ProfileDetail.Id in view but you are assining in controller to ProfileMeta??  Is it clear to you what you are trying?